# Nodemon ts-node can't watch for JavaScript changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemon, ts-node

This is my nodemon.json:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```

My project has both js and ts files and I want it to watch changes in the js files as well but it only restarts when I change index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "js,ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried putting it in an array ["js,ts"], which is why i was getting an error. This works. Thank you.